# How to disable ObjectMapper's invalid date conversion?

Tags: java, spring, jackson, mapping

I have this fragment of code:

```
someValDto = objectMapper.readValue(
     payload, SomeClassDto.class
)
```

the payload is a string that contains a date. If a date is written like: **2000-13-01**, it becomes **2001-01-01** in someValDto, is there a way to disable this in any way?

SomeClassDto has the following structure:

```
public class SomeClassDto {
    @XMLElement(name = "someDate")
    XMLGregorianCalendar someDate;
}
```

The configuration jackson class is:

```
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
class JacksonObjectMapperConfig {
    @Bean
    public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer {
        Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder();
    builder.modules(new JaxbAnnotationModule(), new JavaTimeModule())
    .postConfigurer { it.setDefaultLeniency(false) }
    .defaultUseWrapper(false)
    .serizalitionInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
    .createXmlMapper(true)
    return builder;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want it to throw an error when such an invalid date appears, or somehow accept it unmodified as the 1st day of the 13th month of 2001, or do you want that date to mean the 13th day of January 2001? I think we also need to see the relevant lines of `SomeClassDto`, which would be the date field and related methods and annotations.

Comment: @Jelaby an exception would work for me. I'll add the needed info

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for disabling of ***lenient*** date resolving, which allows the month in the ISO calendar system to be outside the range 1 to 12.

If you're using spring-boot, you can add a property to your `application.yaml` or `application.properties` file:

```
spring.jackson.default-leniency: false
```

But this property will be applied to the whole app. If you don't want to do this, try to configure a specific field in your `SomeClassDto` using Jackson annotation:

```
@JsonFormat(lenient = OptBoolean.FALSE)
private LocalDate date;
```

Note, that this property also applies to date-time format, i.e. if you have this property set to false and your date format is defined as yyyyMMdd you won't be able to parse a date like "yyyy-MM-dd" because of a strict mode.

Comment: unfortunately, that didn't work for me. I've tried application.properties way as well as including that in  .postConfigurer in jacksonObjectMapperConfig

Comment: @razzledazzle88 can you please provide code how you instantiate or configure your `ObjectMapper` instance?

Comment: sure! I'll edit my post

Comment: check the post!

Answer (score 1):

Use of LocalDate class introduced in java8 will be more stable in such cases.

Add the below maven dependency in your pom.xml

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype/jackson-datatype-jsr310 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
    <version>2.13.3</version>
</dependency>
```

and instantiate the ObjectMapper like below

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = JsonMapper.builder().addModule(new JavaTimeModule()).build();
```

modify the datatype to LocalDate

```
@XMLElement(name = "someDate")
private LocalDate someDate;
```

This would throw some error in case of any invalid date is passed. Also make sure the date format is passed in the format : **yyyy-MM-dd**

Comment: Nope, It is the same story with "2000-13-32", I was not specific enough for the clarity of the example

Comment: What is "2000-13-32" ? . This looks like a invalid date .

Comment: That's the point. If there are more than 31 days, it converts it to the next month, as in 01-32 -> 02-01, same for months

Comment: Ok. so the expected output is that, the program should throw some error in such cases . Is that right ?

Comment: yeah, I want to catch an exception in try-catch block when the invalid date of that kind is in the payload.

Comment: Ok. I have edited my answer now. Can you please give a try

Comment: I wish I could use any other type, but XMLGregorianCalendar is a generated type, I cannot change it. I've also used a JavaTimeModule setting already